# How to create a Generic lambda expression. Many of my entities perform the same Lambda expression predicate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, lambda, repository-pattern

I use Entity Framework 4.
How can I perform a Generic Where Lambda Clause.?

I Have many Entity that need the same Where Query.

```
public Func<SupplierTypeText, bool> GetLmbLang()
{
    return (p => p.LangID == 1);
}


public Func<ProductText, bool> GetLmbLang()
{
    return (p => p.LangID == 1);
}


public Func<CategoryText, bool> GetLmbLang()
{
    return (p => p.LangID == 1);
}
```

I would like to have a generic method like

```
//public interface IRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
public Func<T, bool> GenericGetLmbLang()
{
    return (p => p.LangID == 1);
}
```

For the  moment, I hardcoded Language ID == 1, that will be from the user session to make it dynamic.

That's would be very usefull if I Can directly call the GetLmbLang() Directly in the Where clause.

```
 var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new
            {
                model,
                SupType = _db.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(a => GenericGetLmbLang())
            });
```

**------UPDATE--------**

Here is what I Trying and nothing works.

My Base Class

```
 public class BaseGenericModel
    {
        public int LangID { get; set; }

        public Func<BaseGenericModel, bool> GetLmbLang()
        {
            return (p => p.LangID == 1);
        }

    }
```

My interface is

```
   public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseGenericModel
   {
        Func<T, bool> GetLmbLang();
   }


   public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseGenericModel
   {

       public Func<T, bool> GetLmbLang()
       {
          return (p => p.LangID == 1);
       }
   }
```

I Can't call this repository form my SupplierTypeText,ProductText,CategoryText. That's doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have three different types all having the LangID property. I would make them derive from a common base class where this property is defined:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int LangID { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a single method:

```
public Func<BaseClass, bool> GetLmbLang()
{
    return (p => p.LangID == 1);
}
```

An interface containing this property could also be used.

If you want to make it generic you could but you will still need a generic constraint to indicate a common base type if you want to use the `LangID` property:

```
public class SomeRepository<T> where T: BaseClass
{
    public Func<T, bool> GetLmbLang()
    {
        return (p => p.LangID == 1);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I Use entity Framework 4. How can I make SupplierTypeText,ProductText,CategoryText derived from BaseClass to use your Generic GetLmbLang() Method.

Comment: These class SupplierTypeText,ProductText,CategoryText Cannot derived from BaseClass because they already derived from EntityObject

Comment: Then make them implement an interface.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand how to do that. I'll read about interface and try it. I Made interface for all my repository, and each interface is for a single Class Model. @Darin , thanks for your help, I'll give you news soon.

Comment: Ok I figured out. Thanks for your help Darin.